# How do I force an exchange database to become "active" in "Active Manager"

Tags: exchange-2010, disaster-recovery

How do I force a passive node to become "active" when the active manager says it's needing a full sync?

**Background**
We had a catastrophic failure where all that remains is a single edb file.  No backups.  No log files.

The database that remains is on the "passive" copy.  The "active" copy is missing, but the server is active.

The Exchange console reports that the edb file needs to be reseeded, however there is no source to reseed from.

1. How do I make the "invalid" database file (missing logs) valid?  (ESEUtil of course, but I'm talking in context of the active manager)
2. How do I make exchange's active manager recognize this as a valid database to use as a primary?  (same question, said differently)

Comment: RTFM for the ESEUTIL utility, command line based. SInce the dawn of time that is the tool to fix any and all exchange database issues - IF the database is recoverable (you may loose data though). In case of desasters - lesson 1: learn what a backup is ;)

Comment: @tomtom the issue is with the Active manager, I clarified.  This is in relation to my DialTone question http://serverfault.com/q/604947/51457

Comment: Run eseutil first to see what you can fix in that DB. Then, and only then, can you try to make it active.